# Jersey + Jackson 1.9.11 UTF8 issue

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'm using a Jersey WS (2.5) with Jackson 1.9.1.1 and i have an issue with encoding.

i was testing with this text:

```
őúüóöüáű.sqadaud121.-.űúóüóaé í
```

When i return plain text, it is fine.

When i return it manually as a JSON, (so i add [ and ] to the String and set @Produces to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, it is perfect. In this scenario, i just still return String.

But when i use a Pojo, it breaks. See:

```
@GET
@Path("/testUTF")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TestEntity testUTF() {
    TestEntity te = new TestEntity();
    te.setTestText("őúüóöüáű.sqadaud121.-.űúóüóaé í");
    return te;
}
```

This will output totally broken string. This exactly:

```
{"testText":"Q������q.sqadaud121.-.q����a� �"}
```

This made me realize this is an issue with Jackson. I cannot update to Jackson 2.x as it is built with Java7 and we still use Java6.
Anyone any idea?

What I've tried so far:

1) Setting @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8") - had no effect
2) Creating a CharsetResponseFilter and set the charset there - had no effect

Comment: Totally broken how? What is the output you have?

Comment: Updated my question. As soon as i start using a custom POJO instead of a String, it breaks.

Comment: Given the output you have it means the encoding used does not support _any_ accentuated character. Ouch. Looks like it's trying with US-ASCII. Had you used Jackson 2.x maybe I could have helped a little, but 1.9.x... Well, it is just too old. I can't understand why Jersey 2.x sticks with 1.9.x to be honest

Comment: By curiosity, what does .setTestText() do? Simply assign to a `String`?

Comment: Yes, only an assignment.